# Dropzone remove RemoveLink on file success

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Is there any way to delete the removeLink from the file on success?
I have tried this inside of my `init` function:

```
this.on("success", function (file) {
                $(this).find(".dv-remove").remove();
            });
```

but it didn't work. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one in you're success method.

this.options['dictRemoveFile'] = "";

this is object of you're dropzone.